# Как объединить 4 многомерных массивов в 1 многомерный

Tags: php

Я выгружаю 4 разных таблицы из MySQL с разными ключами. Мне нужно их объединить в один массив. Сортировать я их буду по дате (но это не важно и я знаю как это сделать).

Как я это вижу:

```
foreach ($rows2 as $msgs2) { 
  $arraynew = array_merge($arraynew, array('cost' => $msgs2['vivod'], 'date' => $msgs2['date'], 'type' => '1'));
}

foreach ($rows3 as $msgs3) { 
  $arraynew = array_merge($arraynew, array('cost' => $msgs3['price'], 'date' => $msgs3['data'], 'type' => '2'));
}

foreach ($rows4 as $msgs4) { 
  $arraynew = array_merge($arraynew, array('cost' => $msgs4['price'], 'date' => $msgs4['data'], 'type' => '3'));
 }

foreach ($rows5 as $msgs5) { 
   $arraynew = array_merge($arraynew, array('cost' => $msgs5['cost'], 'date' => $msgs5['data'], 'type' => '4'));
}
```

Но это конечно же не работает.

Comment: А почему не собрать все 4 запроса в один непосредственно на сервере и получить оттуда сразу требуемый массив?

Answer (score 0):

Можно собрать все массивы по такому типу:

```
$row = [];
$new = [];

foreach ($rows3 as $msgs3) {
$row = [
    'cost' => $msgs3['price'],
    'date' => $msgs3['data'],
    'type' => '2'
];
$new[] = $row;
```

}

```
foreach ($rows4 as $msgs4) {
$row = [
    'cost' => $msgs4['price'],
    'date' => $msgs4['data'],
    'type' => '3'
];
$new[] = $row;
```

}

результат будем по такому типу:

```
$new = [
0 => [
    'cost' => 'price',
    'date' => 'data',
    'type' => '2'
],
1 => [
    'cost' => 'price',
    'date' => 'data',
    'type' => '2'
],
```

]

Comment: не работает, краш)

Comment: $row = []; ругается на []

Comment: если у вас php постарше версии 7, используйте объявление массивов по принципу: $nameArray = array(); Точно сказать не могу в какой версии изменили конструкцию $a = array(); на $a = [];